# How to end setTimeout and running function when event triggered

Tags: javascript, html, recursion, animation, addeventlistener

I'm trying to create a multiple `div` animation where they all move when scrolled, when I wheel up it doesn't trigger the `else if` actions and doesn't cancel the running `setTimeout` function.

```js
class Animation{
        constructor(){
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
                document.addEventListener("wheel", this.wheelHandler);
            });
            this.callFunction = [];
            this.timer = [];
        }

        wheelHandler = (event) => {
            if(event.target.matches('.login-background')){
                const parser = new DOMParser();
                const loginElbg = document.querySelectorAll('.login-background')[0].innerHTML;
                const parseHTML = parser.parseFromString(loginElbg,'text/html');
                const plusEls = Array.from(parseHTML.querySelectorAll('.login-background__plus')).map((element) => element);
                plusEls.forEach((plusEl, index) => {
                    let el = document.querySelectorAll('.login-background__plus')[index];
                    let speed = parseFloat(el.getAttribute('data-animate-speed'));
                    let x_axis = el.getBoundingClientRect();
                    let x_axis_left = parseFloat(x_axis.left);
                    let z_distance = (x_axis_left + (speed*5));
                    let bodyRect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
                    let that = this;
                    let movement = event.deltaY;
                    if(this.callFunction[index] !== "undefined"){
                        this.callFunction[index] = function(){
                            that.animateObjects(el,speed,z_distance,x_axis_left,movement,index);
                        }
                        this.timer[index] = setTimeout(this.callFunction[index],100);
                    }
                    if(this.callFunction[index] === "function"){
                        clearTimeout(this.timer[index]);
                        this.callFunction[index] = function(){
                            that.animateObjects(el,speed,z_distance,x_axis_left,movement,index);
                        }
                        this.timer[index] = setTimeout(this.callFunction[index],100);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        animateObjects = (el,speed,z_distance,x_axis,movement,index) => {
            let newX_axis = x_axis;
            let targetEl = el;
            let that = this;
            this.callFunction[index] = function(){
                that.animateObjects(el,speed,z_distance,newX_axis,movement);
            }
            console.log(movement);
            if(movement > 0){
                newX_axis += (speed*2);
                el.style.transform = `translate3d(${newX_axis}px, 0, 0)`;
                if(newX_axis < z_distance){
                    // console.log(newX_axis + " != " + z_distance, newX_axis < z_distance);
                    setTimeout(this.callFunction[index],100);
                }else{
                    // console.log(newX_axis + " != " + z_distance, newX_axis < z_distance);
                    return;
                }
            }else if(movement < 0){
                newX_axis -= (speed*2);
                el.style.transform = `translate3d(${newX_axis}px, 0, 0)`;
                if(newX_axis > z_distance){
                    // console.log(newX_axis + " != " + z_distance, newX_axis < z_distance);
                    setTimeout(this.callFunction[index],100);
                }else{
                    // console.log(newX_axis + " != " + z_distance, newX_axis < z_distance);
                    return;
                }
            }else{
                return;
            }
        }
    }
const animate = new Animation();
```

```html
        <section class="login">
            <div class="login-background">
                <div class="login-background__plus" data-animate-speed="2" data-animate-distance="60" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; top: 30px; left: 60px; background-color: #ccc;">
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                </div>
                <div class="login-background__plus" data-animate-speed="1" data-animate-distance="80" style="height: 100px; width: 100px;top: 600px;left: 80px;background-color: #ccc;">
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                </div>
                <div class="login-background__plus" data-animate-speed="3" data-animate-distance="800" style="height: 300px;width: 300px;top: 80px;left: 800px;background-color: #ccc;">
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                </div>
                <div class="login-background__plus" data-animate-speed="0.5" data-animate-distance="500" style="height: 80px; width: 80px; top: 90px; left: 500px; background-color: #ccc;">
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                </div>
                <div class="login-background__plus" data-animate-speed="1" data-animate-distance="300" style="height: 100px; width: 100px; top: 400px; left: 300px; background-color: #ccc;">
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="login__wrapper">
                <h2 class="login__title">Login</h2>
            
                <label for="customer_email">Email Address</label>
                <input type="email" name="customer[email]" />
            
                <label for="customer_password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="customer[password]" />
            
                <input type="submit" value="Sign In" />
            </div>
        </section>
```

Smooth transition and the `div`s don't jump and where able to move left and right smoothly with the event listener